# Prove that the process Zt is covariance stationary if and only if Xt is covariance stationary

Tags: time-series, self-study, covariance

[image]

I would really appreciate it if someone could help show and explain please.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Start by writing the auto-covariance of $Z_t$:
$$\begin{align}\operatorname{cov}(Z_t,Z_{t-j})&=\mathbb E[Z_t Z_{t-j}]-\mathbb E[Z_t]\mathbb E[Z_{t-j}]\\&=\mathbb E[X_tX_{t-j}]+\mathbb E[v_tv_{t-j}]-\mathbb E[X_t]\mathbb E[X_{t-j}]\end{align}$$

Next steps:

- Simplify the expression to contain the covariances of $X_t$ and $v_t$
- Decide what should be satisfied in order for the RHS expression to be independent of $t$